# how to fix macro definition too big error

Tags: c++, c, macros, npapi, firebreath

While compiling my project (npapi plugin -firebreath) on Visual Studio 2010, I get following error:

```
fatal error RC1011: compiler limit : 'FBSTRING_X11MIMEType': macro definition too big
```

The macro is big but it compiles without any issue in gcc (Linux). I can only fix the above error by decreasing the macro length, but that is not a solution to the problem. Please help me with this issue.

**Updated: Here is the macro**

```
#define FBSTRING_X11MIMEType \
                        "application/zip::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/pdf::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/octet-stream::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/postscript::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-msdownload::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-gtar::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-gzip::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-iso::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-unknown::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-compress::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/mac-binary::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/macbinary::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-binary::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-macbinary::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-bzip2::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-bzip::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-compressed::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-tar::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/gnutar::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-zip-compressed::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-7z-compressed::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-debian-package::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-deb::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-iso9660-image::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-ms-application::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-rar-compressed::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-rar::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/rar::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-rpm::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/arj::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-msdos-program::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/msi::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/exe::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-exe::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/dos-exe::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-winexe::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/msdos-windows::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-iso-image::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/force-download::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/java-archive::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-flareget::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/metalink+xml::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/x-cd-image::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/octet-string::My Plugin ;" \
                        "application/download::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/quicktime::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-sgi-movie::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-mpeg::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-mpeq2a::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/avi::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/msvideo::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-msvideo::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/3gpp::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/mp4::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/webm::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/mov::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-f4v::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-flv::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/flv::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-m4v::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-matroska::My Plugin ;" \
                        "video/x-ms-wmv::My Plugin ;" \
                        "flv-application/octet-stream::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/mpeg::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/x-mpeg::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/mpeg3::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/x-mpeg-3::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/mp4::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/ogg::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/webm::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/x-ms-wma::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/x-wav::My Plugin ;" \
                        "audio/mp3::My Plugin ;" \
                        ""
      #define FBSTRING_MIMEType   FBSTRING_MIMETypeList
```

Comment: Hard to help unless you post the macro definition.

Comment: i also had exactly same problem, with VS2k8. I almost thought solution does exist for this problem. Then reinstalled VS, and boom -- error was no more. I still don;t know what happened after reinstalling, but i got away with it.

Comment: Macro is automatically generated by the Firebreath by reading a config file

Comment: The macro is generated by firebreath framework

Comment: so what is your mimetype in the PluginConfig file? that's what it's generated from.  You could also post the define from the generated file, which will be in build/projects/(plugin name)/gen/config.h

Comment: @taxilian I managed to get pass the macro error by replacing "my plugin" with " ", but now I am stuck with fatal error RC10056: in firebreathwin.rc at following line 63 VALUE "MIMEType", FBSTRING_MIMETypeList

Comment: Why do you need to handle all those mimetypes? I wonder if we couldn't suggest a better approach if we knew what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of things, you simply have too many mimetypes that you're trying to handle.  Since FireBreath handles the mimetypes using a define, I suspect you won't get this to work without rewriting some firebreath internals

Comment: It works in Linux, I even managed to get pass the macro error by replacing "my plugin" with " ", but now I am stuck with fatal error RC10056: in firebreathwin.rc at following line 63 VALUE "MIMEType", FBSTRING_MIMETypeList

Comment: That could also be related to the length; but again, go look at the generated file

Comment: yes it is because of length, in the generated resource file, the build fails when VALUE "MIMEType", FBSTRING_MIMETypeList, what changes can I make to get it working. Also I had to edit configure_template.cmake file, as there was issue with this too.

Comment: You could shorten the number of mimetypes you're trying to handle; you're trying to hijack a whole bunch of other plugins (such as pdf) which is really strongly frowned upon by the browser manufacturers.  FireBreath was never intended to do something like this.  I don't know offhand what you could change in firebreath to make it work; you'd probably have to look at it on a case by case basis.